# Why does the list comprehension give off a different result than the for loop in this case (python)?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

The language I am using is Python 3.10.
I have been hunting a bug in my program for more than a week now, and it turns out that it was caused by my list comprehensions not giving the results I expected.
I have written a simple example to showcase this behaviour:

```
alist = [1,2,3]

d = {}
for a in alist:
d[a] = lambda x: a + x

print([d[a](1) for a in alist])

for a in alist:
print(d[a](1))
```

This results to:

```
[4, 4, 4]
2
3
4
```

Does anyone know what is happening here? I guess that I will stop using dictionnaries of functions, but it still seems like it should work.

Comment: for lambda, `a` is considered non-local variable, so its value is whatever it is in the enclosing scope - it doesn't "remember" the value from the time of definition. It's not the same `a` that is later used in list comprehension. You can force the `a` to be local variable of lambda by doing `lambda x, a=a: a + x` - aka making it an argument with default value of whatever `a` is at the time of lambda's definition

Comment: Please fix the indents in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll make matszwecja's comment the accepted answer, thanks!

for lambda, a is considered non-local variable, so its value is whatever it is in the enclosing scope. It's not the same a that is later used in list comprehension. You can force the a to be local variable by doing lambda x, a=a: a + x - aka making it an argument with default value of whatever a is at the time of lambda's definition